# Why the init process creates different processes?Why cannot it create different threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

As we all know that init process is the first process which is being executed and results in the creation of further inevitable processes.Now, the question is that ,what could be the matter of primarily concern that would have lead the init process to create processes rather than threads.

Comment: not clear what you are talking about. Is it an operating system? Which one?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I am talking about UNIX operating system.

Comment: Only the majority close vote reason is shown. Mine was "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com)."  This question is about OS architecture. Stack Overflow is about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about how most Unix systems start up.  Well, let's forget about init for a moment and ask, why would *any* process create another process instead of creating another thread?

The whole point of having an operating system at all is to allow different "programs" to co-exist and share the hardware without clobbering one another.  Threads, by definition, exist in the same address space.  There is no way to protect one thread's data structures from being clobbered by another thread in the same process except to write the code in such a way that the threads cooperate with one another.  Threads within a process are always part of the same "program".

The Unix init process spawns other processes because many of the services in a Unix system are provided by different programs.  And why is that?  Partly it's for historical reasons.  Nobody had ever heard of "threads" when Unix was new.  But also, it's a convenient way to organize components that are not related to one another.  The person who writes the ssh daemon does not have to worry about whether it plays nicely with the cron daemon or not.  Since they are separate programs, the operating system automatically hides them/protects them from each other the same way it hides/protects user programs.

Comment: even i was thinking the same...but just wanted to clarify   myself.Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that threads in the same address space are not protected from other threads. If however, such a protection exists (like in Java), then using threads instead of processes make sense.

I know at least one operating system where all system activities were performed by threads in single system process - the one for [Elbrus1 and 2](http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Elbrus_%28computer%29) computers (modern Elbruses are operated by Linux). This was possible because of tagged memory architecture, inherited from Burrows machines. Probably Burrows machines worked that way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "the tagged memory architecture"?...what's the difference between the conventional UNIX architecture and "tagged memory architecture" ?

Comment: each memory word has tag bits, describing word's type, and arbitrary references to memory cannot be constructed. References also has "size" field, which is checked when an array is accessed.  "tagged memory architecture" can be googled easily.